# Best approach to create a webapp which updates the UI dynamically on his own rest service invocation by an external client

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, websocket

I have a webapp which exposes a rest endpoint. Clients post data to this endpoint. I need to display the content they post in my webapp, without refreshing the UI.

My first approach was to save the posted data on a database and to have an ajax call which will continuously seek for the new data to display. This adds an overhead, because I don't need to save what I receive. 
Secondly, I came across web sockets where a client and server can have full duplex communication.

Is there any better way of doing this?

P.S: My rest endpoints are developed using spring boot.

Comment: What frameworks or technologies are you using on the front webapp?

Comment: why not use angular js , it supports data binding principle so you dont need to update the front end manually.

Comment: If you need real time updates in your browser-based UI, and you want to avoid polling the server for updates, websockets are a good solution. However they won't work with your REST service. You may want to use a websocket to simply communicate to the frontend that the backend's data has changed, and then you can use your ajax/REST mechanism to get the changed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally there are three ways to get the client updated on a server event: polling, long-polling, and server-side push. They all have their pros and cons:

## Polling

Polling is the easiest way of implementing this. You just need a timer on the client side and that's it. Repeatedly query the server for updates and reuse the code you already have.

Especially if you have many clients, the server may get flooded by a large amount GET requests. This may impose computational as well as network overhead. You can mitigate this by using a caching proxy on the server side (either as part of your application or as a separate artifact/service/node/cluster). Caching GET requests is normally quite easy.

Polling may not seem to be the most elegant solution but in many cases it is good enough. In fact polling can be considered the "normal" rest-full way to do this. HTTP specifies mechanisms like the [if-modified-since header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3) which are used to improve polling.

## Long-Polling

Long-polling works by making the GET request a blocking operation. The client makes a request and the server blocks until there is new data. Then the request (which might have been made long ago) is answered.

This dramatically reduces the network load. But there are several drawbacks: First of all you can easily get this wrong. For example when you combine this approach with server-side pooling of session beans your bean pool can get used up quite fast and you have a wonderful denial-of-service.

Furthermore long-polling does not work well with certain firewall configurations. Some firewalls may decide that this TCP connection has been quiet for too long and regards it as aborted. It then may silently discard any data belonging to the connection.

Caching-proxies and other intermediaries may also not like long-polling -- although I have no concrete experience I can share here.

Although I spent quite some time writing about the drawbacks, there are cases when long-polling is the best solution. You just need to know what you are doing.

## Server-Side Push

The server can also directly inform the clients about a change. Websockets are a standard which details this approach. You can use any other API for establishing TCP connections but in many cases websockets are the way to go. Essentially a TCP connection is left open (just like in long-polling) and the server uses it to push changes to the client.

This approach is on a network-level similar to the long-polling approach. Because of that it also shares some of the drawbacks. For example you can get the same firewall issues. This is one of the reasons why websocket endpoints should send heartbeats.

In the end it depends on your concrete requirements which solution is best. I'd recommend using a simple polling mechanism if you are fine with polling every ten seconds or less frequently and if this doesn't get you into trouble with battery usage or data transmission volume on the client (e.g. you are building a smartphone app). If polling is not sufficient, consider the other two options.